# bash - executing multiple scripts from a script

Tags: bash

I have a crontab entry that will run a 'worker' script hourly.
Within the 'worker' script I have multiple paths to other scripts like so;

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "project-worker"
echo "Script to run checks on all jobs!"
source /home/user/project/project-jobs/cleanuptest1/project-mon-cleanuptest1.sh
source /home/user/project/project-jobs/sedtest1/project-mon-sedtest1.sh
jobslot=empty
exit
```

My issue is it only seems to be running the first script (cleanuptest1.sh) and ignoring the rest.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong at all?  I read to call other scripts from within a script I should use `source` but is where I'm going wrong, it can't be used for multiple instances?

Many thanks in adavance!

Comment: Why are you using `source` to run the scripts? Unless you need environment variables from those scripts in the main one, best practice would dictate that you use `.` instead.

Comment: If you *do* need to use `source`/`.`, you need to make sure the script isn't calling `exit`.

Comment: Thanks guys for you responses - @chepner - should I remove `exit` from script?  Do you think it will be exiting the shell before the scripts finish?  Just curious why I should remove it?

Comment: @keefer, imagine it as literally copying the subscript and pasting it inside the caller script substituting the `source` call.

Comment: @xvan Ahhhh - get you- thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source should only be used if you need to preserve the called script environment on the callee.

If that's not the case you can execute the subscripts in subshells.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "project-worker"
echo "Script to run checks on all jobs!"
bash /home/user/project/project-jobs/cleanuptest1/project-mon-cleanuptest1.sh
bash /home/user/project/project-jobs/sedtest1/project-mon-sedtest1.sh
jobslot=empty
exit
```